# The correct way to user custom UITableViewCells

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, uitableview

I have seen a lot of different ways of implementing custom cells in a table view.
Like different file owners, get it from bundle and call the the latest obj of the array and a lot more.

But all did not feel right.

What is the best and correct way to create and use custom table view cells (with interface builder).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think Storyboards are the new proper way. I use this method:

http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.com/2009/09/table-view-cells-in-interface-builder.html

And it works quite well. I think it's somewhat proper in that you are asking the OS to do most of the work, although it's a little sneaky that the cell is assigned to a property as part of the NIB loading as a side effect.

Comment: I have used that way, and it is pretty nice. But if you want to use the custom table view cell at multiple table views in different view controllers, its not going to work, because you only have one file owner for the cell.

Comment: You can just copy and past the cell from one view controller to another.

Comment: I played a but, and it is actually pretty easy. Thanks for the tips

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem. For me it is now solved with storyboards in ios5.

Comment: Do you have an link or explanation of how YOU do it? I want to use the custom cell at multiple different table views in different view controllers.